# Get IPv6 on PPPoE in Ubuntu

Tags: ipv6, dhcpv6

I have a strange situation here. If anyone can help, please do so.

We're talking about a Linux Box running as Router using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, with 2 interfaces: "lan" - which connects to my internal LAN and "wan" - which connects to my ISP.

However, my ISP requires PPPoE connection, so, basically, the "wan" interface is used only a starter for the ppp0 interface.

**My problem is that I cannot get IPv6 global address on this server.**

I am able to successfully connect to my ISP.
I already followed the tutorial from here: http://gruffi.be/mediawiki/index.php/Ipv6_with_PPPoE_on_Ubuntu , but it doesn't work for me.

So, here is what I did:

1. /etc/ppp/options:

   ```
   +ipv6 ipv6cp-use-ipaddr
   ```
2. /etc/sysctl.conf:

   ```
   net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1

   net.ipv6.conf.ppp0.accept_ra=2
   ```
3. /etc/wide-dhcpv6/dhcp6c.conf:

   ```
   interface ppp0 {

       send ia-pd 2;
       send ia-na 1;
   };

   # Use subnets from the prefix with id 0
   id-assoc pd 2 {
       prefix-interface lan {
           # Assign subnet 1 to eth0
           sla-len 8; # <----- BELANGRIJK: 8 omdat ons klein net 64 en ons groot 56 is en dat het verschil is
           sla-id 2;
       };
   };

   id-assoc na 1 { };
   ```
4. /etc/radvd.conf:

   ```
   interface lan
   {
       AdvSendAdvert on;
       prefix ::/64
       {
           AdvOnLink on;
           AdvAutonomous on;
           AdvRouterAddr on;
       };
   RDNSS 2001:4860:4860::8888  2001:4860:4860::8844
           {
                   # AdvRDNSSLifetime 3600;
           };
   };
   ```

My ISP told me that it doesn't use Router Advertisement, however it uses DHCPv6 Prefix Delegation and offers /64 subnets.

The problem is that I tried more configs from the net, non of them worked for me.

When I "ifconfig ppp0", it says:

```
inet 1.2.3.4 ...
inet6 fe80::xxxx:yyyy
```

No sign of a global IPv6 address.

If I turn on debugging on wide DHCP client and I examine /var/log/syslog, I see that it tries to send Solicit messages to ff02::1:2%ppp0 and the timers reset.
I get no reply.

However, router advertisements are working, both on "ppp0" and on my internal lan, because I have a Default Route: "default via fe80::1" when I "ip -6 r".
However, no global IPv6 address.

I suspect it something to do with DHCP.
The address is not obtained correcly.

I can ping:

```
ping6 fe80::1%ppp0
64 bytes from...
```

But when trying to "ping6 google.com", it says: "Beyond scope of source address"

I need to do 2 things, in the long run:

1. Try to get a global IPv6 address on "ppp0" so my websites can be accesible from IPv6 addresses (DNS already taken care of)
2. I need to forward whatever /64 prefix my ISP gives me, let's say: "2001:abcd:dead:beef::/64" to my internal computers, but using a fixed part for the internal computers.[/COLOR]

For example:

```
Computer 1: 2001:abcd:dead:beef::1/64
Computer 2: 2001:abcd:dead:beef::2/64
Computer 3: 2001:abcd:dead:beef::3/64
```

I do NOT want EUI-64 addresses, NOR do I want Private Addresses.
I want my computers assigned an ORDERly IPv6 address with the prefix given, regardless of the dynamic prefix.

For example, after reboot, I might get "2001:1234:beef:dead::/64".
I want the same Host-part allocation using "*::1", "*::2", and so on...

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

For #1, your solution may be with the ipv6 option in your pppd conf:

+ipv6  Enable the IPv6CP and IPv6 protocols.

ipv6 ,
      Set  the  local  and/or  remote 64-bit interface identifier.
      Either one may be omitted. The identifier must be  specified
      in   standard   ascii   notation  of  IPv6  addresses  (e.g.
      ::dead:beef). If the ipv6cp-use-ipaddr option is given,  the
      local  identifier is the local IPv4 address (see above).  On
      systems which supports  a  unique  persistent  id,  such  as
      EUI-48    derived    from    the   Ethernet   MAC   address,
      ipv6cp-use-persistent option can be used to replace the ipv6
      , option. **Otherwise the identifier is randomized**.

So if you used ipv6 ::1, would that do what you wanted?  As an experiment you can replace ipv6cp-use-ipaddr with ipv6cp-use-persistent instead... that should give you a predictable global ipv6 for your ppp0.  From there you can start tweaking your wide-dhcpv6 and radvd....